# How to display the records from the first table and match the records from the second table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two tables, One is for student details and second is for stud_marks.

I am inserting the personal information in student table like

```
  s_id  | name   | mobile     | email  
    1   | asdff  |1234567831  |asd@gmail.com
    2   | kjhgg  |1231231231  |mnhg@gmail.com
    <!--many more-->
```

and I am inserting the student marks like

```
m_id    |sub_name    |mark       | stu_id    |date_of_added
1       |asdasd      |30         | 1       |2019-06-16 17:31:07
2       |oiuytr      |40         | 1       |2019-06-16 17:31:07
3       |okjhyt      |50         | 2       |2019-06-20 20:12:09
4       |ppoiuj      |60         | 1       |2019-06-22 11:41:34
<!--many more-->
```

Now, what query I have to use and display the single records. Like I have to display the student 1 record. so My expected output is

```
 s_id  | name   | mobile     | email  
   1   | asdff  |1234567831  |asd@gmail.com


m_id    |sub_name    |mark       | stu_id    |date_of_added
1       |asdasd      |30         | 1       |2019-06-16 17:31:07
2       |oiuytr      |40         | 1       |2019-06-16 17:31:07
4       |ppoiuj      |60         | 1       |2019-06-22 11:41:34
```

I am on the edit page and there I have to display the records like

```
name:-asdff
mobile:-1234567831
Email:-asd@gmail.com

<!--subject details-->
Sub_name Mark
asdasd   30         
oiuytr   40
ppoiuj   60
```

I can display the records on the HTML page. Personal information is display. I can use for each for displaying the subject details.

I am using CodeIgniter.

I tried below query but I am getting 3 records.

```
SELECT * FROM `student` LEFT JOIN stud_marks ON student.s_id=stud_marks.stu_id WHERE student.s_id=1
```

the output of the query is

```
1 asdff 1234567831 asd@gmail.com 1 asdasd 30 1 2019-06-16 17:31:07

1 asdff 1234567831 asd@gmail.com 2 asdasd 40 1 2019-06-16 17:31:07

1 asdff 1234567831 asd@gmail.com 4 asdasd 60 1 2019-06-22 11:41:34
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: So where is the problem ? You are using WHERE clause for s_id=1 so there are 3 records for that s_id and those you are getting as a query result. What is your expected output ? We can modify query accordingly.

Comment: @RajeshKakkad, Thanks for the response. I already added my expected output in the question. Please check 3rd section of the code.

Comment: The code you mentioned returns output as you expected. Do you want help in displaying records as you have mentioned in example or do you have any problem with data returned by the query ?

Comment: I have to issue with the query because if you check I am getting 3 records which are correct because I used to join and I have 3 records related to the id 1 in student mark. Now how do I display on edit page because student personal details are unique but student mark are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//assuming your database connection will be in $con
$sql="SELECT * FROM `student` LEFT JOIN stud_marks ON   student.s_id=stud_marks.stu_id WHERE student.s_id=1";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 $name=$row['name'];
 $mobile=$row['mobile'];
 $email=$row['email'];
 $marks[]=$row['mark'];
 $sub_names[]=$row['sub_name'];
 }
 $records=count($sub_names);
 echo 'Name :'.$name; echo '<br>';
 echo 'Mobile :'.$mobile; echo '<br>';
 echo 'Email :'.$email; echo '<br>';
 echo '------'; echo '<br>';
 echo 'Subject    Marks'; echo '<br>';
 for ($x = 0; $x <= $records; $x++) {
 echo "$sub_names[$x]  $marks[$x]   <br>";
 }
 echo '------'; echo '<br>';
```

CodeIgniter example to extract data:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        $name=$row['name'];
        $mobile=$row['mobile'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $marks[]=$row['marks'];
        $sub_names[]=$row['sub_names'];
}
```

For displaying the result, no change in code starting from `$records=count($sub_names)` in my previous example.

Comment: @questionbank Tested working Ok on my servers just now.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: I am not using CodeIgniter but there is just minor change in accessing the data as described here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html in detail and accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246878/codeigniter-echo-query-result-array - specifically see *result_array()* on codeigniter page mentioned. Instead of while loop in my example, follow their *foreach* loop.

Comment: @questionbank - check method for codeigniter I added in my answer. Moreover, refer pages I mentioned above. This should put you on the track.